# Cannot trigger cancel button action after processing results returned

Tags: acumatica

Within the Acumatica 19.201.0070 framework I have created a custom processing page that utilizes `PXFilteredProcessing` with the old style processing UI `public override bool IsProcessing => false;` I have defined a cancel button (below) that will clear the graph and set some values of the processing filter.

```
    public PXCancel<NPMasterSubGeneratorFilter> Cancel;

    [PXCancelButton()]
    protected virtual IEnumerable cancel(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        NPMasterSubGeneratorFilter row = Filter.Current;
        if (row != null)
        {
            this.Clear();
            Filter.SetValueExt<NPMasterSubGeneratorFilter.segmentID>(Filter.Current, row.SegmentID);
            if (!(row.NewSegment ?? false)) Filter.SetValueExt<NPMasterSubGeneratorFilter.segmentValue>(Filter.Current, row.SegmentValue);
        }
        return adapter.Get();
    }
```

This works perfectly fine except for a single use case, after processing results are shown if the user then presses the cancel button the corresponding action is never hit. ( My fellow office devs state that core Acumatica processing pages seem to operate the same. )

[image]

Setting of the processing delegate is within the filter RowSelected event.

```
GeneratedSubs.SetProcessDelegate(list => CreateSubaccounts(list, row));
```

I have implemented a few iterations of my processing method but the current is below.

```
    protected virtual void CreateSubaccounts(List<NPGeneratedSub> subs, NPMasterSubGeneratorFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter.NewSegment ?? false)
        {
            try
            {
                SegmentMaint segGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SegmentMaint>();
                segGraph.Segment.Update(segGraph.Segment.Search<Segment.dimensionID, Segment.segmentID>(AADimension.Subaccount, filter.SegmentID.Value));
                SegmentValue value = segGraph.Values.Insert(new SegmentValue() { Value = filter.SegmentValue, Descr = filter.Description });
                segGraph.Actions.PressSave();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new PXOperationCompletedSingleErrorException(NonProfitPlusMessages.SegmentValueCannotCreate);
            }
        }

        SubAccountMaint subGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SubAccountMaint>();
        NPSubAccountMaintExtension subGraphExt = subGraph.GetExtension<NPSubAccountMaintExtension>();
        subGraphExt.save.ConfirmSaving = false;

        Sub newSub;

        bool errored = false;
        foreach (NPGeneratedSub sub in subs)
        {
            PXProcessing<NPGeneratedSub>.SetCurrentItem(sub);
            try
            {
                newSub = subGraph.SubRecords.Insert(new Sub() { SubCD = sub.SubCD, Description = sub.Description });
                subGraph.Save.Press();
                subGraph.Clear();
                PXProcessing<NPGeneratedSub>.SetProcessed();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                PXProcessing<NPGeneratedSub>.SetError(e);

                errored = true;
            }
        }
        if (errored)
        {
            throw new PXOperationCompletedWithErrorException();
        }
    }
```

What needs to be adjusted to allow the buttons action to be triggered on press after processing results have been returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After stepping through the javascript I discovered that it wasn't sending a request to the server when you click the cancel button on this screen after processing. The reason is because SuppressActions is getting set to true on the Cancel PXToolBarButton. I compared what I was seeing on this screen to what was happening on screens that work correctly and realized that Acumatica is supposed to set SuppressActions to true on the Schedule drop down PXToolBarButton but for some reason, on this screen, it is incorrectly setting it to true on whatever button is after the Schedule drop down button.

I looked through the code in PX.Web.UI and it looks like they set SuppressActions to true when a drop down button is disabled and PXProcessing adds a FieldSelecting event to the Schedule button which disables the button after you click process. However, I didn't notice any obvious issues as to why the code would be setting it on the wrong PXToolBarButton so someone will likely need to debug the code and see what's going on (we are unable to debug code in PX.Web.UI.dll).

I tried commenting out the other grids in the aspx file that aren't related to the PXProcessing view and this resolved the issue. So my guess would be that having multiple grids on the PXProcessing screen somehow causes a bug where it sets SuppressActions on the wrong PXToolBarButton. However, since the multiple grids are a business requirement, removing them is not a solution. Instead, I would suggest moving all buttons that are after the schedule button to be before the schedule button. To do this, just declare the PXActions before the PXFilteredProcessing view in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

- Override `IsDirty` property
- Use `PXAction` instead of `PXCancel`
- Add `PXUIField` attribute with enable rights
- action name should start from **lowercase** letter
- delegate name should start from **uppercase** letter

see code below

```
public override bool IsDirty => false;
public override bool IsProcessing
{
    get { return false;}
    set { }
}

public PXAction<NPMasterSubGeneratorFilter> cancel;

[PXUIField(MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXCancelButton]
protected virtual IEnumerable Cancel(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    NPMasterSubGeneratorFilter row = Filter.Current;
    if (row != null)
    {
        this.Clear();
        Filter.SetValueExt<NPMasterSubGeneratorFilter.segmentID>(Filter.Current, row.SegmentID);
        if (!(row.NewSegment ?? false)) Filter.SetValueExt<NPMasterSubGeneratorFilter.segmentValue>(Filter.Current, row.SegmentValue);
    }
    return adapter.Get();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue and behavior remains the same as current implementation.

Comment: Strange, works fine on my environment, looks like we missed something. What Acumatica version do you use? Could you please provide more details about your processing delegate, how do you process selected records, how do you mark them as successfully processed?

Comment: Added additional details